# simple preloader for jquery load function

Tags: jquery, html

i know how to load a page in jquery  and somehow i know how to use success but what if that page failed

im looking for a way to show loader image before the page loaded and if the page failed show a message

this is the function i wrote :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#loading").html("<img src='images/preload.gif' />");
    $(".thumb").load("stat.html");

});
```

now i want to change it in a way it shows preloader and the message if failed

Comment: Read  detailed steps to create full page loader animation here. http://www.kvcodes.com/2017/07/simple-jquery-preloader-css-image/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The load function has a calledback that provides the status of the request. It looks something like this...

```
$(selector).load(url,[],[callbackFn(response,success,xhr)]);
```

So you can do something like this:

```
$(".thumb").load("stat.html",function(response,status,xhr){
  if(status == "error") {
    //Something went wrong, have your error fallback code here
  }
});
```

You can find an example here: http://jsbin.com/uxisa3/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$.ajax` instead of `post` so that you will have more control on the lifecycle using callback methods. In your case, you can use `beforeSend`, `error`, `complete` callbacks (which are self explanatory)

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "stat.html",
   data: "name=John&location=Boston",
   beforeSend: function(){
        $("#loading").html("<img src='images/preload.gif' />");
   },
   success: function(msg){
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
   },
   error: function(e){alert(e);}
 });
```